# Changing my users table column, "email" to "Email and "password" to "Password" in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an existing database but the naming convention is not the same as the default of laravel. My database table "users" has  a column name of "Id" , "Username" and "Password". How can i totally setup those naming to be accepted in laravel auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize getter and setter method, and make the first letter of the parameter capitol. This will transformer the accesses, to the correct database column name.

```
class YourModel extends Model {
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        return parent::getAttribute(ucfirst($key));
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        return parent::setAttribute(ucfirst($key), $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel accessor and mutator in User model to overcome the field mismatch with the existing user table

```
    public function getEmailAttribute() 
    {
        return $this->attributes['Email'];
    }

    public function setEmailAttribute($value) 
    {
        $this->attributes['Email'] = $value;
    }

    public function getUsernameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['Username'];
    }

    public function setUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['Username'] = $value;
    }
```